# How to empty the back-history in firefox tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

After a day of SO my back history of the firefox tab is pretty long.

How can I empty it, without closing the tab and opening it again? Can I run a GreaseMonkey script to do that?

Edit:
After following the ideas of Noitidart, I now have in the scratchpad the history (window.history) with window.history.length elements. I can go back and forth. But how do I empty it?

Comment: Hey burk did you find the solution?

Comment: @Noitidart: no, I couldn't combine all the links you gave me. Some of them seem obsolete, some need the environment browser and some don't...

Answer (score 0):

Awesome question. I think the only way is to make a firefox addon its a very simple one to make.

Here is some code you can run from scratchpad. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo4STWceGTM

I think it will work from greasmeonkey too.

This some HTML5 stuff but i dont think it will affect more then the current:

[MDN :: Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

This is what we will probably need to use:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIAsyncHistory
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsISHistory#PurgeHistory%28%29
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIBrowserHistory
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIGlobalHistory
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIGlobalHistory2
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIGlobalHistory3
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsINavHistoryService

Comment: Thanks. nslGlobalHistory 1 to 3 seem to be deprecated. How do I use the historyService (last link)? I get a 'Exception: TypeError: Components.classes is undefined'

Comment: Ah, thanks. Any pointer on how to combine all these links to get it to work?